# What's going on the function inside of reduce method in JavaScript? - JavaScript30 exercise

Tags: javascript, methods, reduce

I have been working on the array exercise on Wes Bos's JavaScript30.
Please help me out with [this exercise.](https://youtu.be/HB1ZC7czKRs?t=1340), which is #8.

The code in the video is the following.

```js
const data =['car', 'car', 'truck', 'truck', 'bike', 'walk', 'car', 'van', 'bike', 'walk', 'car', 'van', 'car', 'truck']

const transportation = data.reduce(function(obj, item) {
  if (!obj[item]) {
    obj[item] = 0;
  }
  obj[item]++;
  return obj;
}, {});
console.log(transportation)
```

I tried two versions and get the wrong output or an error, and would like to figure out the difference between the code above and these two. Also, I'd like to understand what was going on with these two codes.

One is the following and the difference is that setting `else` block.

```js
const data = ['car', 'car', 'truck', 'truck', 'bike', 'walk', 'car', 'van', 'bike', 'walk', 'car', 'van', 'car', 'truck']

const transportation = data.reduce(function(obj, item) {
  if (!obj[item]) {
    obj[item] = 0;
  } else {
    obj[item]++;
  }
  return obj;
}, {});

console.log(transportation)
```

This returns the object below.

`{car: 0, truck: 0, bike: 0, walk: 0, van: 0}`

In this case, does `else` detect nothing? How come the function keeps returning the same value zero?

Another one is the following and the difference is putting `return` inside of `else` block.

```js
const data = ['car', 'car', 'truck', 'truck', 'bike', 'walk', 'car', 'van', 'bike', 'walk', 'car', 'van', 'car', 'truck']

const transportation = data.reduce(function(obj, item) {
  if (!obj[item]) {
    obj[item] = 0;
  } else {
    obj[item]++;
    return obj;
  }
}, {});

console.log(transportation)
```

This returns an error saying `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'car' of undefined`.

I understand that to return the object inside `else` block causes an error because this terminates the execution.

However, still don't understand the meaning of that error message.  Should I have defined each object key somewhere in some way?

Comment: Have you used your JS debugger? If not, why not?

Comment: Arguments named `obj` and `item` are unhelpfully vague. Unless that's intentional (which I doubt, but I haven't watched the video you linked to) then that's giving their student viewers a poor example of how to write maintainable and readable software programs.

Comment: FWIW, a lot of us ([ex.](https://twitter.com/jaffathecake/status/1213077702300852224), [ex.](https://twitter.com/bterlson/status/1099010861065068544)) would consider that a very poor use of `reduce`. Since the accumulator never changes (it's always the obj created for the 2nd arg to `reduce`), there's no point in using `reduce` there. It's just over complicated and easy to get wrong (by forgetting to return `obj` from the callback). In that case -- as in nearly all cases except in FP with predefined, reusable reducer functions -- a loop would be simpler to write & read, and more efficient.

Comment: What is `data`?

Comment: In the last example, you never return the obj if there is no `obj[item]`

Comment: You are getting {car: 0, truck: 0, bike: 0, walk: 0, van: 0} because you are initializing value with 0 and 0 is considered as false.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you for your comment! I can't agree more to use `loop` instead.
btw, what does FP mean in this case?

Comment: @Kaho - [Functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming). :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reduce function accept a function and on every iteration whatever value you return will gets assigned to first param(obj in our case). you missed to return, undefined will gets assigned and hence error.

```
const data = ['car', 'car', 'truck', 'truck', 'bike', 'walk', 'car', 'van', 'bike', 'walk', 'car', 'van', 'car', 'truck']

const transportation = data.reduce(function(obj, item) {
    if (!obj[item]) {
        obj[item] = 1;
    } else {
        obj[item]++;
    }
    return obj;
}, {});

console.log(transportation)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = ['car', 'car', 'truck', 'truck', 'bike', 'walk', 'car', 'van', 'bike', 'walk', 'car', 'van', 'car', 'truck']

const transportation = data.reduce(function(obj, item) {
  // if (!obj[item]) { // `obj[item] === 0` ==> `!obj[item] === false`
  if (!(item in obj)) {
    obj[item] = 0;
  } else {
    obj[item]++;
  }
  return obj;
}, {});

console.log(transportation)
```